# Laravel: pass route parameter to filter parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this route (note the filter which is being applied with an optional parameter):

```
Route::get('/greet/{name?}', array(
    'before'    => 'summergreet:optionalNameToCapture',
    function ($name = 'friend') {
        return View::make('greetview', array('name' => $name));
    }
));
```

And the assigned filter:

```
Route::filter('summergreet', function($route, $request, $name = 'amigo')
{
    if (date('m') >= 7 && date('m') <= 9) {
        return View::make('summergreetview', array('name' => $name));
    }
});
```

How can I capture the optional parameter to the route and pass it through to the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
Route::filter('summergreet', function($route, $request, $name = 'amigo')
{
    $name = $route->parameter('name');
    if (date('m') >= 7 && date('m') <= 9) {
        return View::make('summergreetview', array('name' => $name));
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how it works for 'optional' parameters. You might need to check `isset()` or `is_null` on the variable first....

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But then I have to get rid of the parameter substring appended to the filter alias: ":optionalNameToCapture". Seems that it's useless for optional parameters.

Comment: I did this to check whether the parameter is null or not:

$nameFromRoute = $route->parameter('name');
$name = isset($nameFromRoute ) ? $nameFromRoute : $name;

Comment: Rather than useless like I said, I could still use the optional filter  parameter with its default value "amigo", like so: 'before'    => 'summergreet:amigo',  and I wouldn't be forced to provide the parameter in the filter closure with a default value. Not quite sure whether to use one choice or the other.